# python manipulations on lists

Tags: python, string, list, data-manipulation

I have 2 lists

```
l1 = ('A','B','C')
l2 = ('X','Y','Z')
```

I want to create a list based on these 2

result = ('A is same as X', 'B is same as Y', 'C is same as Z')

when I concatenate , I do not get the result I expect
How can I combine the lists ?
Thanks
PMV

Comment: the new list is combing from list1 and list with some text in b/w..something like result = ('A is same as X',  'B is same as Y', ' C is same as Z')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists together which will combine the two lists into a list of tuples and then iterate over those tuples.

```
z = zip(l1,l2) #[(A,X), (B,Y), (C,Z)]

result = ["{0} is the same as {1}".format(t[0], t[1]) for t in z]

# ['A is the same as X', 'B is the same as Y', 'C is the same as Z']
```

Comment: i get this error..iam using py2.7 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-c436eabe4d2e> in <module>()
----> 1 result = ["{0} is the same as {1}".format(t[0], t[1]) for t in zip]

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: Just edited.  Fat fingered the code when typing it into SO.  Was supposed to be `t in z` not `t in zip`

Answer (score 2):

the zip() function can help you here.

```
result = []
for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
    result.append("{0} is same as {1}".format(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a more direct way...

```
>>> map('{} is same as {}'.format, l1, l2)
['A is same as X', 'B is same as Y', 'C is same as Z']
```